# Forwarding variadic parameters to other function in Java like in C++

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Is it possible to accomplish forwarding of parameters in Java like in C++:

```
template <typename ...Params>
void f(Params&&... params)
{
    y(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}
```

E.g. in  a situation when I want to have a single factory function:

```
public static MyClass create( < parameter pack > )
{
    return new MyClass(< forward >);
}
```

having multiple constructors?

It is worth noting that the parameter pack can contain parameters of different types.

Comment: Although you use C++ as an example, since the question isn't about C++, the C++ tag is inappropriate.

Comment: What's the problem with simply passing the parameters further on?

Comment: Aren't they getting forwarded as is since java does not imply copy semantics for classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re your edit:

> It is worth noting that the parameter pack can contain parameters of different types.

That completely changes the question. Reflection is the only way you can accomplish that. Here's an example of the reflection example from below, but getting the parameter types from the actual classes of the passed-in parameter values ([live example](https://ideone.com/QXjF9H)):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Example
{
    public Example(String a) {
        System.out.println("(String): " + a);
        // ...
    }

    public Example(int a, String b) {
        System.out.println("(int, String): " + a + ", " + b);
        // ...
    }

    public Example(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("(String, String): " + a + ", " + b);
        // ...
    }

    static Example create(Object... params) {
        try {
            Class[] paramTypes = new Class[params.length];
            for (int n = 0; n < params.length; ++n) {
                Class cls = params[n].getClass();
                if (cls.equals(Integer.class)) { // You may need this (for int and other primitives)
                    paramTypes[n] = Integer.TYPE;
                } else {
                    paramTypes[n] = cls;
                }
            }
            Constructor ctor = Example.class.getConstructor(paramTypes);
            return (Example)ctor.newInstance(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("parameters not supported");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example e1 = Example.create("foo");
        Example e2 = Example.create(1, "foo");
        Example e3 = Example.create("foo", "bar");
    }
}
```

Obviously a very basic, incomplete example, but hopefully it gets you going the right way. More:

- [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)
- [`java.lang.reflect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)

---

Original answer:

Variadic arguments in Java are syntactic sugar for arrays. Anywhere you can provide a variable argument list, you can provide an array instead:

```
public static MyClass create(SomeType... args)
{
    return new MyClass(args);
}
```

Here's a complete example ([runnable copy](https://ideone.com/Fu3vUm)):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Example
{
    Example(String... strings) {
        System.out.println("strings = " + Arrays.toString(strings));
        // Obviously, in the normal case, a constructor actually does something
        // with the parameters...
    }

    static Example create(String... strings) {
        return new Example(strings);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Example e = Example.create("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

---

> having multiple constructors

If you mean multiple constructors without variadic parameters, you'll have to branch or use reflection; Java doesn't have a built-in mechanism other than reflection that can do it. (I understand C++'s mechanism for this does, which is cool.) Which might be an argument for consolidating them and making one variadic constructor insead.

Branching:

```
class Example
{
    Example(int a) {
        System.out.println("one param: " + a);
        // ...
    }

    Example(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("two params: " + a + ", " + b);
        // ...
    }

    Example(int a, int b, int c) {
        System.out.println("three params: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
        // ...
    }

    static Example create(int... ints) {
        switch (ints.length) {
            case 1:
                return new Example(ints[0]);
            case 2:
                return new Example(ints[0], ints[1]);
            case 3:
                return new Example(ints[0], ints[1], ints[2]);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only 1-3 ints allowed");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Example e = Example.create(1, 2, 3);
    }
}
```

Reflection ([live example](https://ideone.com/5fJogv)):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Example
{
    public Example(String a) {
        System.out.println("one param: " + a);
        // ...
    }

    public Example(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println("two params: " + a + ", " + b);
        // ...
    }

    public Example(String a, String b, String c) {
        System.out.println("three params: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c);
        // ...
    }

    static Example create(String... strings) {
        try {
            Class[] paramTypes = new Class[strings.length];
            Arrays.fill(paramTypes, String.class);
            Constructor ctor = Example.class.getConstructor(paramTypes);
            return (Example)ctor.newInstance((Object[])strings);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(strings.length + " strings not supported");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Example e = Example.create("a", "b", "c");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe for pointing it out more, that arrays are allowed. You might want to add `Example e2 = Example.create(new int[]{1, 2, 3});`

Comment: While I think this is about the best you'll get without reflection (not very appealing here), it's worth noting that it doesn't measure up to the C++ version in all aspects. C++ allows the constructor to have whatever parameter list it needs as long as the arguments match in the end. These parameters and arguments can also be different types and retain their specific types throughout the process with no runtime information.

Comment: @chris - Thanks for that comment, very useful. My update just now (having twigged to the fact that the OP's constructors may not be variadic) hopefully calls that out. But I'll also edit in that info.

Comment: @chris Thank You. I forgot about that, so I edited the question to mention about that.

Comment: @K.Koovalsky, To connect that to the answer, Java's form of this polymorphism is base classes/interfaces. In the most general case, that's `Object`. You lose some compile-time type information, but that's how it is with the two languages being different. It's possible there's a different approach to the overall problem that's more suited to Java.